# Get HTML exact fromated with Jsoup

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I have bounced in to a little problem.
I am getting html from an website and I get it formated correct but one problem here is where its an image there get loads of **whitespaces** and the text are starting really far away.

Is there any good fix for this. Here is how I have done it:

```
public class getDetails extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Document doc,doc_;
        String test;
        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect(Global_URL).get();
            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("entry-content");
            doc_ = Jsoup.parse(elements.toString());
            doc_.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
            doc_.select("br").append("\\n");
            doc_.select("p").prepend("\\n\\n");
            test = doc_.html().replaceAll("\\\\n","\n");
            test = Jsoup.clean(test,"",Whitelist.none(),new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
            dialog_desc = test;
            //dialog_desc = elements.text().toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the HTML you are scraping and clarity on what you are trying to do with adding line breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using **Jsoup.parse()** and **.Html()** I just used the **.Text()** and the problem where solved.